# Python Power Multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie to Python. I was learning the arithmetic in python when I saw this.

5**(5+5) equals 9765625
while 
(5+5)**5 equals 100000

Why does this happens?

I am using Python 3.4.0

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/35598/145059 -- "[Exponentiation is not commutative. This contrasts with addition and multiplication, which are. For example, `2 + 3 = 3 + 2 = 5` and `2 · 3 = 3 · 2 = 6`, but `2**3 = 8`, whereas `3**2 = 9`.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `**` is used to denote 'raised to the power of`

```
a**b --> a raised to the power of b
```

`10**5` and `5**10` are therefore different, giving you different results

```
>>> 10**5
100000

>>> 5**10
9765625
```

This is because `python` evaluates the `(5+5)` first.

```
5**(5+5) --> 5**10 --> 9765625
```

whereas

```
(5+5)**5 --> 10**5 --> 100000
```

Comment: @geeko_zac, Glad I could help. You should probably know that python follows the PEDMAS/BODMAS rules